# How to display data from gridview to textbox into a pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a gridview that displays data from a database and print button that prints a pdf file; However instead of printing in a tabular format; I would place each values into a textbox as seen below. 
This is what I have thus far

```
                sb.Append("<table border = '1'>");
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in sealdata.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append("<th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#000000'>");
                    sb.Append(column.ColumnName);
                    sb.Append("</th>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
                foreach (DataRow row in sealdata.Rows)
                {

                    sb.Append("<tr>");
                    foreach (DataColumn column in sealdata.Columns)
                    {
                        sb.Append("<td>");
                        sb.Append(row[column]);
                        sb.Append("</td>");

                    }
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr></table>");
                sb.Append("<br />");
```

Example of how I want it to displayed on the pdf file
[image]

Data on the page
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your example shows only how data from a single `DataRow` should be displayed. But what about other rows, where should they be placed?

Nevertheless, try this:

```
sb.Append("<table>");

DataRow row = sealdata.Rows[0];

foreach (DataColumn column in sealdata.Columns)
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");
    sb.AppendFormat("<th>{0}:</th>", column.ColumnName);
    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", row[column]);
    sb.Append("</tr>");
}

sb.Append("</table>");
sb.Append("<br />");
```